# Are there alternatives to Shutter-lok fasteners?

Tags: fastener, shutters

I have [this kind of fastener](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Shutter-Lok) on my shutters and it seems that every 3-5 years I am buying a new shutter because they break off and the shutter gets torn up in a storm or I am trying to liquid nail them back in the brick facade of my house.

[image: Shutter-lok fastener]

I hate the idea of putting them back up knowing that in 3 years I will be drilling yet another hole in my brick.

Is there an alternative that will last longer and still keep this look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shutter-loks are basically vinyl nails with annular rings to grip. They are meant to be removable by snipping them, confirming that they have low strength.

Why not simply use screws of a similar length? You need a weatherproof type, such as [these](http://www.homedepot.com/p/t/203159911?productId=203159911&storeId=10051&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&ci_sku=203159911&cm_mmc=shopping-_-googleads-_-pla-_-203159911&ci_gpa=pla#.Udxpr_mKK8C) which are recommended for shutters.

[image: painted screws]

You could also use coated [deck screws](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Deck-Mate-9-x-3-1-2-in-Coarse-Tan-Coated-Steel-Flat-Head-Exterior-Wood-Screws-1-lb-Pack-16350/100348691#.UdxqWPmKK8A) which come in several colors and weather well.

[image: deck screw]

Comment: And if he can't find ones of the right colour he could always dab some black paint on the end of them once installed!

Comment: Thanks. Ordered these (top ones) from Home Depot site. Hopefully I can use my same masonry bit.

Comment: @lazfish If you are going into concrete, stucco or brick, you will need anchors for masonry. Shutters are low weight, so almost any type intended for masonry should do. The whole size will be larger though. If you want direct to masonry without anchors, you need a specialized masonry screw like a Tapcon. A bit more finicky than anchors, but solid.